# Extract text from nested attributes of the li element with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

How should I access text from 'strong' and 'span' tags nested under 11 'li' tags in the picture below using Python Selenium?

I'm looking to store the output in dict format:
{"Name": Name, 
Address: No.250/1, 16th and 17th cross..., 
State: Karnataka, 
City: Bangalore}

Here's the HTML:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
for elem in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"[id^='arrowex']"))):
    NGO_element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("faq-sub-content exempted-result")
    NGO_name = (driver.find_element_by_class_name("fc-blue fquph")).text.replace(NGO_name_pancard.text, '')
    NGO_name_pancard = driver.find_element_by_class_name("pan-id")
    ul = driver.find_element_by_class_name("exempted-detail")
    for item in (ul.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")):
```

Comment: Share your URL for more details.

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code to get values from `strong` and `span` nodes of each `li` as key-value pair:

```
data = {}
for item in (ul.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")):
    data[item.find_element_by_tag_name('strong').text] = item.find_element_by_tag_name('span').text
```

The output of data should looks like `{'Address': 'No.250/1, 16th and 17th cross...', 'State': 'Karnataka', 'City': 'Bangalore', etc}`